# Missing option 'Run test' in test plans

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, test-plan

I have configured my test plans according to page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops and configured a build with corresponding release / stage on the test plan.

I want to be able to select my tests from the list for execution and select the 'Run test' option to execute the automated tests for my selection but this button is missing!
I do have the option 'Run test with options' and I can manually select the build with release / stage to run the corresponding tests but this is additional work and can cause errors when the wrong release is selected.

How can I get the button 'Run test' to appear in the test plan execution screen?

[Documentation Microsoft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpJt2.jpg)

[My test plan execution options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAzrY.jpg)

[My configuration settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLROO.jpg)

Comment: Hi @JeroenR did you try **Run for web application**. this option works as Run test. Please check below answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "run test" option in the test plan execution now.

If you configure your test plan by following the [Microsoft document](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops). You can click **run for web application** to run your tests against the configured build and release stage in **Test plan settings**(It is kind of misleading, for my test project isnot a web application. But it is working as **Run test**).

[image]

For most of the time You need to choose run with option and select the build to run you automatic tests. 
For the project is under agile development process, new version of the build continuously get updated. There is no meaning to always run tests against the same build. And the test need to be executed for the scenarios like when you get a new version of build or deployed to new stages.

However you can still go the [developer community forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(click suggest a feature and choose azure devops) to suggest this feature to be enabled. Hope the development will consider implementing it in the future sprint.